# Просуммировать пары значений двух столбцов в ASP .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть веб-страница, которая содержит таблицу со значениями, которые берутся из бд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Модель таблицы следующая:

```
 public class MyTable
    {
        public int ts_num { get; set; } 
        public DateTime pl_date_first { get; set; } 
        public DateTime pl_date_last { get; set; } 
        public String pl_num { get; set; } 
        public String pl_vod { get; set; } 
        public decimal tank1_dn { get; set; } 
        public decimal tank2_dn { get; set; } 
        public int tank1_dn_count { get; set; } 
        public int tank2_dn_count { get; set; }
    }
```

Отображение веб-страницы в Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyTable(DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
        {            
            return View(await _azdb.MyTable.Where(x => x.pl_date_first >= startdate && x.pl_date_first <= enddate.Value.AddDays(1)).ToListAsync());
        }
```

Нужно отобразить столбец tank_dn_all = tank1_dn+tank2_dn, то есть столбец, который отображал бы попарные суммы значений из строк tank1_dn и tank2_dn.
Я пробовал реализовать суммирование либо в самой модели (тогда в столбце суммы отображаются нули), либо в html-форме (тогда происходит просто конкатенация строк значений обоих столбцов). 
Каким способом можно осуществить данное действие?

Answer (score 1):

В итоге решил проблему на уровне БД, добавив дополнительные поля суммы в таблицу.